# Swift 3 / iOS 10 Today View Widget

Tags: swift3, ios10, xcode8, today-extension, ios10-today-widget

How to show "Show More" button in today widget (similar to news app as attached here)?
I found this on [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html)  but there are some changes in swift 3 / iOS 10. This seems to be like something new in iOS 10.

[image]

Comment: @TwoStraws I think you were mean not to share the answer but just pointing to paid tutorial. Stackoverflow is not the place for you!

Comment: That's why I posted a comment, not an answer. Furthermore, your question breaks Stack Overflow's posting rules, which is why it has two votes to close – asking for links to tutorials is considered too broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the height of the new iOS 10 Today Widget/Extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129047/what-is-the-height-of-the-new-ios-10-today-widget-extension)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code did the trick of showing "Show More"

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: CGFloat(items.count)*121 + 44)

    if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *) {
        self.extensionContext?.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = .expanded
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}

// For iOS 10
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
@available(iOSApplicationExtension 10.0, *)
func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    self.preferredContentSize = (activeDisplayMode == .expanded) ? CGSize(width: 320, height: CGFloat(items.count)*121 + 44) : CGSize(width: maxSize.width, height: 110)
}
```